# Creating an image whith GIMP hiding another image unless we add a color filter in real life

Tags: colors, gimp, vision

The idea is like the inverse of Ishihara test (http://www.colour-blindness.com/colour-blindness-tests/ishihara-colour-test-plates/).

I want to create with GIMP an image that showing something and then if I add a color layer, for exemple green glasses, then I see something new appearing.

I've searching far in Google and so but didn't found anything. Do you know how would I make this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on-topic here - what is the programming aspect of your task?

Answer (score 1):

The Ishihara tests use the principle of combining things color blind persons cannot differentiate.

Coloured glass filters will only remove other colours from what you see. They don't add something. Therefor it is not possible to create a digital image that contains no information unless seen through a colour filter.

The only thing you can do is overlap your "hidden" information with high contrast colour noise.

Like here:

[image]

Using the glasses / filter only improves the visibility. The information is not added. It was always there.